# link de una tabla a otra tabla react

Tags: reactjs, tablas

Tengo una tabla en la cual hay en la lista tengo un link y quiero que al dar link me muestre el contenido en otra tabla dentro de la misma pagina que recargue una parte pero no logro realizarlo.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera que se recargue en la parte inferior son dos componentes distintos pero con la misma estructura adjunto código

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import MUIDataTable from 'mui-datatables'
import {NavigateNext} from '@material-ui/icons';
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import Producto from '../Producto'

class Guia extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      error: null,
      isLoaded: false,
      guia: [],
      columns: [{
        name: "id",
        label: "ID"
      }, {
        name: "nombreUsuario",
        label: "Nombre Usuario"
      }, {
        name: "cantidad",
        label: "Cantidad"
      }, {
        name: "fecha",
        label: "Fecha"
      }, {
        name: "observaciones",
        label: "Observaciones"
      }, {
        name: "observacionescheck",
        label: "Observacion Final"
      }, {
        name: "estado",
        label: "Estado"
      }, {
        name: "Accion",
        options: {
          customBodyRender: (value, tableMeta, updateValue) => (
            <Button color="primary" onClick={this.updListaProducto(tableMeta.rowData[0])}>
              <NavigateNext/>
            </Button>
          )
        }
      }],
      options: {
        filter: true,
        filterType: "dropdown",
        responsive: "stacked",
        selectableRows: false
      }
    }
  }

  updListaProducto(id) {
    console.log(id)
    // Producto.state({producto: []})
  }

  listaGuia() {
    let api_token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data')).api_token
    fetch("http://192.168.2.126:82/api/getListaGuia?api_token=" + api_token, {
      method: 'GET'
    })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            guia: result
          });
        },
        (error) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            error
          });
        }
      )
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.listaGuia();
  }

  render() {
    const {error, isLoaded, guia, columns, options} = this.state
    if (error) {
      return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>
    } else if (!isLoaded) {
      return <div>Cargando...</div>
    } else {
      return (
        <>
          <MUIDataTable
            title={"Lista de Guias"}
            data={guia}
            columns={columns} W
            options={options}
          />
          <Producto/>
        </>
      )
    }
  }
}

export default Guia;
```

Comment: Asumo que `updListaProducto` sería la función que cargue la información en el componente `<Producto/>` ¿estoy en lo correcto? Creo que deberías llamar a un `setState` ahí que luego puedas pasárselo en la función `render` al componente. No se de que otra forma ayudarte, ya que no das mayor detalle de tu problema.

Comment: lo que ocurre es que no funciona no se como hacer funcionar este tipo de proceso que del listado de una tabla cargue otra tabla no encuentro la manera si tuvieras un ejemplo que te agradecería